# Was New Republic Supreme Chancellor Villecham a nod to Neville Chamberlain?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, names

Was New Republic Supreme Chancellor [Villecham](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lanever_Villecham) (named in TFA Visual Dictionary) a nod to [[Ne]ville Cham[berlain]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville_Chamberlain#Road_to_Munich_.28March_1938_.E2.80.93_September_1938.29)?

I'm looking for facts from creative team, not just guesses based on historical parallels (which are obvious).

Comment: You even get "ne", "ver", and "la" in his first name. Lanever Villecham is an anagram of Neville Chamverla.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Now, someone needs to tie in Cornelius Fudge to all of this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Yes.

[Confirmed](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/680149954615062528) on Twitter by [Pablo Hidalgo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo), creative executive in story development at Lucasfilm (which I think makes this information canon):

[image: tweet]

Comment: Wow, I was expecting someone would have to go on twitter and ask the man. Good find!

Comment: @DVK That's exactly what I did: went back in time and set up a Twitter account to ask. I feel you aren't appreciating the lengths I went to in answering your question, discovering time travel and all :-(

Comment: (Just kidding: actually the first few results when I typed "chancellor villecham neville chamberlain" into Google all linked to this tweet.)

Comment: Actually, at some point or another, Pablo Hidalgo's Twitter account explicitly stated in its description "don't take anything said here as canon"

Comment: I like your time travel story better. It has less implications that I was lazy and didn't do my research.